# Positioning an input rotated 90 degrees inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I made input range vertical via javascript like this:

```
var range_pitch = document.createElement("input");
range_pitch.setAttribute("type", "range");
range_pitch.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(90deg)";
range_pitch.style.mozTransform = "rotate(90deg)";
range_pitch.style.oTransform = "rotate(90deg)";
range_pitch.style.msTransform = "rotate(90deg)";
range_pitch.style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
```

But I cannot place it into created `<div>` (doesn't work for me):

```
vertical_slider.appendChild( range_pitch );
document.body.appendChild( vertical_slider );
```

Here is **[My fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bimbochobot/mn8twepj/1/)**

Is there any solution, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Fixed fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mn8twepj/19/)**

Check the DOM in your browser console you can see that the `input` is already inside the `div`, you should just adjust CSS, check example bellow.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
  var vertical_slider = document.createElement('div');
  vertical_slider.id = 'vertical_slider';

  var osa_y_panorama = 0.6;
  var range_pitch = document.createElement("input");
  range_pitch.setAttribute("type", "range");
  range_pitch.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(90deg)";
  range_pitch.style.mozTransform = "rotate(90deg)";
  range_pitch.style.oTransform = "rotate(90deg)";
  range_pitch.style.msTransform = "rotate(90deg)";
  range_pitch.style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
  range_pitch.min = "0";
  range_pitch.max = "218";
  range_pitch.step = "0.6";
  range_pitch.defaultValue = osa_y_panorama;


  vertical_slider.appendChild( range_pitch );
  document.body.appendChild( vertical_slider );
```

```css
#vertical_slider
{
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 218px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

input{
  position: relative;
  top:93px;
  right: 83px;
  width:200px;
}
```

Comment: I guess you mean to adjust CSS of range_pitch element, right?

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much! And is it possible to make that input range as big as div with CSS? (218px)

Answer (score 0):

The problem come from your css rotation to the input, if you check the DOM, your element is inside but the rotation make it look outside.

You can use this css to hot fix it :

```
input {
  position: relative;
  right: 70px;
  top: 100px;
}
```